# Opening Files from File Browser

Tags: files, browser, default

I seem to have an issue I don't see documented elsewhere.  When I am attempting to open a file from the file browser (be it a video, audio, or other document), I am unable to double-click on the file and have the Ubuntu system open the default application.  I have to manually open the application from the launcher, then in that application manually browse to and open the file.  How do I fix this?

```
Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Comment: Have you tried different file-manager?

Comment: What "file browser" are you using?

Comment: I believe by default it's a single click

Comment: This is with Nautilus.  I changed the default behavior in properties to open via a single click, changed the default applications, and was unable to get it to work.  Apparently the Ubuntu App Program has a number of one-star reviews stating that they are having the same problem.  I have to right click > open with custom application >  select application. 
Is there a version of nautilus I can roll back to in apt-get that works?